# what does (x<<13) ^ x mean?

Tags: expression

What language is this expression and what does it mean?

```
x = (x << 13) ^x;
```

Answer (score 5):

It could be any number of languages.  In `C` and several other languages, `<<` is a [left-shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) operator, and `^` is a [bitwise XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator.

Answer (score 3):

Both `<<` and `^` ( left-shift and xor respectively) are bitwise operators and many languages like C, C++, Java have them

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators

Answer (score 3):

In C, this would be "left shift x by 13 binary places, and take the XOR of this and x".

Answer (score 1):

It is any C-derived language.

It means that the author only knows part of C.  Otherwise they’d’ve written

```
 x ^= x << 13;
```

to xor something with itself multiplied by 2¹³.

Answer (score 0):

*What language is this expression*

That is C syntax. This could be any [C-based programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-based_programming_languages) (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript). However, this is not PHP or Perl because sigils are not used.

*what does it mean?*

I actually can't read that code either - syntactic languages such as C are very hard to read. From what I understand from what other people said this is equivalent to:

```
(bit-xor (bit-shift-left x 13) x)
```

Comment: A language with a complicated syntax and an operator precedence table, basically anything non-Lisp.

Comment: Oh.  You mean any normal language, then, the kind that gets used for 99.999% of industrial computing.

Comment: Yeah, I mean the languages that are responsible for all the unmaintainable, bloated, insecure, bug-ridden, overpriced, proprietary malware that comes out of the computing industry.

Comment: yep -- all that **and** everything else, too.